# MySQL query slowdown with added another AND clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm using Doctrine2 in Symfony2 project and the ORM produces the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(p0_.id) AS sclr0 
FROM Purchase p0_ 
LEFT JOIN USER u1_ ON p0_.user_id = u1_.id 
LEFT JOIN Config c2_ ON u1_.id = c2_.id AND (c2_.deletedAt IS NULL) 
WHERE (u1_.organization_id = 7) AND (p0_.deletedAt IS NULL);
```

It returns 176336 and it takes server good 30 seconds to launch it.

If I remove `AND (p0_.deletedAt IS NULL)` clause it takes 0.1 sec. Why does the AND clause (not OR!), which should make the resutset always <= that without it, slow it down so heavily? 
To prove that, here is the screenshot from `SELECT PROFILES;` output after the query with AND:

[image: Profiler output WITH AND]

Here is the output of exactly the same query, but without `AND (p0_.deletedAt IS NULL)`, note that the newer queries are appended below (see Query_ID = 5):

[image: Profiler output WITHOUT AND]

To make sure this is not a cache matter, I launched another same query without `AND (p0_.deletedAt IS NULL)` and SQL_NO_CACHE added (see Query_ID = 8)

This is reproducible both in Windows with `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.14, for Win64 (x86_64)` and Ubuntu with `5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log`. Here is the same experiment on Linux more powerful server:

```
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.00025925 | SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(p0_.id) AS sclr0
FROM Purchase p0_
LEFT JOIN USER u1_ ON p0_.user_id = u1_.id
LEFT JOIN Config c2_ ON u1_.id = c2_.id AND (c2_.deletedAt IS NULL)
WHERE (u1_.organization_id = 7)                               |
|        2 | 0.04896325 | SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(p0_.id) AS sclr0
FROM Purchase p0_
LEFT JOIN `User` u1_ ON p0_.user_id = u1_.id
LEFT JOIN Config c2_ ON u1_.id = c2_.id AND (c2_.deletedAt IS NULL)
WHERE (u1_.organization_id = 7)                             |
|        3 | 8.35424850 | SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(p0_.id) AS sclr0  FROM Purchase p0_  LEFT JOIN `User` u1_ ON p0_.user_id = u1_.id  LEFT JOIN Config c2_ ON u1_.id = c2_.id AND (c2_.deletedAt IS NULL)  WHERE (u1_.organization_id = 7) AND (p0_.deletedAt IS NULL) |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query with `AND (p0_.deletedAt IS NULL)` and `INNER JOIN`'s takes about the same time: 
[image: Prilfer output with INNER JOIN]

Here are the `EXPLAIN` outputs for with and without `AND`:

[image: EXPLAIN with AND]

[image: EXPLAIN without AND]

---

**Table structures.**

**Purchase:**

```
CREATE TABLE `purchase` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requestor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_supplier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deletedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `amount` double NOT NULL,
  `xml` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `comments` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `payload_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `error` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipping_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipping_phone_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_phone` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_fax` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_deliver_to_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipping_deliver_to_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_payment_info_amount_percent` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temporary_old_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `number_organization` (`number`,`organization_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9861B36DA76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9861B36DD68143A9` (`credit_card_user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9861B36DA7F43455` (`requestor_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9861B36D1A81C9F7` (`organization_supplier_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9861B36D32C8A3DE` (`organization_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9861B36D52D06999` (`user_address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9861B36D1A81C9F7` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_supplier_id`) REFERENCES `organizationsupplier` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9861B36D32C8A3DE` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES `organization` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9861B36D52D06999` FOREIGN KEY (`user_address_id`) REFERENCES `useraddress` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9861B36DA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9861B36DA7F43455` FOREIGN KEY (`requestor_id`) REFERENCES `requestor` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9861B36DD68143A9` FOREIGN KEY (`credit_card_user_id`) REFERENCES `creditcarduser` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=359199 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**User**

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `roles` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json_array)',
  `firstname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_enabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login_attempts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_changed_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `allow_all_suppliers` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_2DA1797732C8A3DE` (`organization_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2DA1797732C8A3DE` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES `organization` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2DA17977BF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `config` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**Config**

```
CREATE TABLE `config` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deletedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `discr` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: You should prepend `explain` to your queries so you can see what is actually being run.  Also, do you get the same problem if you using inner joins instead of outer joins?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: see, I updated my question. It takes the same with inner joins and I also put there explain outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the query with the `AND` clause, MySQL has to look up the actual purchase record to retrieve the `deletedAt` value. According to the `EXPLAIN` result, this occurs 35 times for each 1968 user records.

Without the `AND`, MySQL is able to use the `IDX_9861B36DA76ED395` index to retrieve the purchase `user_id` and `id` (for the `COUNT`), so it doesn't have to look up the actual purchase record for any other information.

Adding the following multi-column index may improve the situation: `purchase (user_id, deletedAt)`